# using `#` in config file value

Tags: configuration

Many config files use the hash sign `#` to mark the beginning of a comment. How do I set values that contain such a sign without it being interpreted as a comment?

[edit]
actually, it seems to be a real problem. See https://superuser.com/questions/431539/special-characters-in-ssmtp-password for more info

Answer (score 2):

You need to either escape it:

```
\#
```

or quote it

```
"#"
```

or

```
'#'
```

For some config file formats you won't need that as it is only considered a comment when the # is at the beginning of a line, e.g. [Apache config files](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html).

> Lines that **begin** with the hash character "#" are considered comments, and are ignored

Comment: in this case, I am using the ssmtp software and I have a sharp in the AuthPass variable. Quoting or escaping does not work in this case neither for apache config files.

Comment: You should not need to quote them for apache files: "Lines that **begin with** the hash character "#" are considered comments, and are ignored.".

Comment: strange. Maybe something else goes bad in apache config. Problem remains for ssmtp. Thanks for your advice

Comment: it should be [the same](https://linux.die.net/man/5/ssmtp.conf) for ssmtp but it seems not to be

Comment: The exact thing I tried is : sending an email with *with_#_password*, changing my password to *without_#_password*. Only the second option works. Setting back the password to *other_#_password* breaks the authentication.

Comment: sorry, I cannot help you with this.

Comment: I found this : https://superuser.com/questions/431539/special-characters-in-ssmtp-password

Comment: https://github.com/huginn/huginn/wiki/SMTP-passwords-with-special-characters-need-to-be-surrounded-by-quotes says to use quotes with smtp ;-) `SMTP_PASSWORD="My$Password#With&SpecialChars"` is used as an example

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: in my case, I had to feed the variable directly in the command line arguments of the program.

e.g.

```
ssmtp -ap "PasswordWith#InIt" ...
```

it might not work for other programs.

Comment: 1 issue: this WILL reveal the password to the system. `ps -ef | grep ssmtp` will show it

Comment: You're right, it's not secure. Using an environment variable to store the password is slightly better, but if security is the problem, you would rather use a password manager.